# Strikethrough with GitHub Markdown

Tags: markdown, github

Using HTML tags is supposed to work with GitHub [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) but, in particular, `<s>text</s>` is not working for me. It used to work on the now deprecated [live preview](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/preview.html) page, but not on preview of `README.md` file. It works on wikis. I didn't find any special syntax for strikethrough on the [Markdown: Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) page.

Is it not possible?

Answer (score 784, accepted):

Use ~~double tildes around the words~~.

Comment: won't work on multiple paragraphs at once, but this is good enough too.. tnx

Comment: Nice @iangreenleaf

Comment: Tildes can be confusing when reading markdown as-is.

Comment: Works in bitbucket md files. Nice.

Comment: In [slack](http://slack.com), they use `~` as the delimiter for [strikethrough text](https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Formatting-your-messages).

Comment: This also works on [dillinger.io](//dillinger.io). Joined this community just to upvote.

Comment: Didn't work for me in the answer editor on Stack Overflow/Exchange.

Comment: It is also working on https://trello.com.

Comment: It also works in the visualstudio.com wiki preview, yayy

Comment: @Nevena <strike>strike</strike> works on multiple paragraphs. Check out the other answer below.

Comment: <strike>strike</strike> and ~~tildes around the words~~

Comment: This did not work for me, perhaps because I'm trying to use it over multiple lines.

Comment: Works in azure devops, cool.

Comment: It only works on Github in single lines, and won't show up in the Preview tab of the editor. Not sure if this is a bug though.

Answer (score 178):

I just used the following syntax

`<del> ... </del>`

successfully on GitHub in an issue description.

Comment: This is a good answer too, since Markdown accepts arbitrary HTML tags. Depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: Nice! Was looking for this to use on an SE site and indeed this is working on SE too

Comment: Does not work with Gitlab :(

Comment: Works with Gitlab!

Comment: Works with Azure devops but so does ~~ and latter is better IMO. )

Answer (score 99):

I know this is an old question, but I don't see a very detailed answer of the possibilities to strikethrough your text. So here's my answer:

There are several ways to do it:

1. `<strike>strike</strike>` → <strike>strike</strike>
2. `<del>strike</del>` → <del>strike</del>
3. `<s>strike</s>` → <s>strike</s>
4. `~~strike~~` → ~~strike~~
5. `~strike~` → ~strike~

Because tildes don't work on Stack Exchange *(later: SE)* platforms, the HTML syntax is the most correct way to strike your text. This syntax is a little "hack" to do the same thing instead of the markdown notations.

Because there is no universal notation for markdown text, the notations may be different for each platform. Here is an overview for several platforms:

- On [Slack](https://slack.com/), you must use a single tilde
- On [GitHub](https://github.com/), you can use all notations
- On SE platforms, you must use the [HTML syntax notations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), as said above *(except for comments)*

The [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) only mentions that you can use double tilde, but you can use everything.

Comment: Great answer, it's more comprehensive than the accepted, as it provides alternatives to places where ~~ doesn't work ~~ In Multimarkdown and Marked2, the tilde doesn't work for me.

Comment: To bad <s>the html</s> doesn't work in comments.

Comment: I just confirmed that on Keybase chat,  `~~` around characters does strike them out.

Comment: Slack takes one tilde only: ~like so~ in messages

Comment: Does not work in <s>comments</s>.

Answer (score 11):

> Use <kbd>~</kbd> to enclose whatever you want to strike.

Here's a GIF.

[image: animated gif showing use of tilde]

Just use <kbd>~</kbd> character at the start and the end in markdown.

`~strike~`

Answer (score -2):

`<s>` and `</s>` is the only thing working
~ and ~~ both of them are not working under