# Highlight deleted and added lines with GitHub Markdown

Tags: github, markdown

How can I highlight deleted and added lines like in [this comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2766#issuecomment-29604370)? How do I make it look like a git diff?

Do I have to use HTML? Or is there some tricky syntax [like strikethrough?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/strikethrough-with-github-markdown)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is done by using a code block with the "diff" syntax. The raw markdown would look something like this:

````
One small step for 
```diff
-man
+humankind
```
````

I've made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/incarnate/bf38f3f289b8de0f96a2) also that demonstrates the code (click "Raw" to view the markdown).

Comment: Thanks! Not knowing this had been bugging me for a long time. Out of curiosity, where is this documented? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can see the complete list of languages they do syntax highlighting for here: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml It is so long, diff was bound to be there!